# The set of rational as subspace

Tags: general-topology

Why the every compact subset of rational numbers as subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ has empty interior? is this because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense?

Comment: actually, every subset of the rational numbers, period, has empty interior.  It's because the complement of $\mathbb{R}$ is dense.

Answer (score 2):

If some $\Bbb Q$-compact $K\subset\Bbb Q$ had non-empty interior, then there would be some non-empty $\Bbb R$-open set $V$ such that $\Bbb Q\cap V\subseteq K.$ But $K$ is necessarily $\Bbb R$-compact since it is $\Bbb Q$-compact (why?), so is $\Bbb R$-closed. However, taking any point $x$ of $V\setminus\Bbb Q,$ we have that $x$ is a limit point of $\Bbb Q\cap V$ (so of $K$) that does not lie in $\Bbb Q$ (so does not lie in $K$). Contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

No, but because $\mathbb {I}$ is dense in $\mathbb R$, thus for every point $p$ in your compact subset you find irrational points near to $p$, which of course do not belong to your compact subset. But this means, that $p$ is not an inner point hence the interior is empty.